Would using a Virtual Machine (e.g. Parallels Desktop) allow me to bypass the authorization request for email--tracking software?
I am looking for a way to use an email-tracking software such as Mailbutler on MacOS Sonoma.
So far, I have been unsuccessful, because Mailbutler keeps asking me for authorization on my Sonoma and this has to come to my IT Department, which is unresponsive.
I was wondering if, by installing a virtual machine like Parallels Desktop, I could bypass this problem? Other suggestions, alternatively?

Most likely not.

Mailbutler on your Mac is not going to tell you whether I've read your email on mine.

@benwiggy apparently it does: https://help.mailbutler.io/help/how-to-view-tracking-details-with-mailbutler . I can confirm with Ventura this used to work no problem for me

People still have to enable read receipts. https://www.mailbutler.io/blog/email/email-read-receipt/ Also, Apple explicitly prevents pixel tracking in images.

bypass the problem using Parallels Desktop? Running a Mac VM or a Windows VM or a Linux VM or... ? Only if Mailbutler behaves differently on other OS (EG not likely) Also it is trivially easy to prevent mail tracking software as @benwiggy so succinctly states. Besides we are not here to help you bypass security policies put in place by your workplace or school. If IT is unresponsive they likely consider this non-work related and may look askance at you doing this.
